# Multiline if else ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, block

I know this questions has been touched on elsewhere, but I'm slightly confused about the proper syntax for multi-line (block?) `if else` statements in ruby.

As an example:

```
if condition then
  do something
  do somethingelse
  do yetanotherthing
  done
else
  do acompletelyunrelatedthing
done
```

I understand that the `then` statement is required if multiple lines are used, but is the `done` before the `else` necessary? This seems like it would break out of the `if...else` context. When I do include this `done` I get:

`syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'`

When I don't include it I get:

`syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `then` keyword is only used if you need to put the whole thing on one line (to separate the condition from the action to take if true):

```
if condition then do_something else do_something_different end
```

If you don't want it all one line (usually you don't), the syntax is as in Doorknob's answer.

Comment: It is correct that `then` is for one liners, however, stylistically, we don't write if/else statements on one line. For simple versions use a ternary statement otherwise break it into separate lines.

Comment: Can u write one example of above? I want to write multiple lines in if condition body

Answer (score 5):

Um... there is no `done` keyword in Ruby. Here is the correct syntax:

```
if condition
  # do stuff
else
  # do other stuff
end
```

The `then` keyword is not needed either.

Comment: note the `# do stuff` is a comment, that you replace with the code you want executed